# How to turn on/off Autonomous Life from a Choregraphe Project

Tags: pepper

Autonomous life can be controlled from within Choregraphe's UI as well as by pressing the chest button twice on the robot, however, how can this be done from a Choregraphe project?
After browsing the list of tools in the Box Library, it is unclear which tool can be used for this.

When Autonomous Life is on, the robot, in order to appear *alive*, makes small motions with its head, arms, and legs.  The behaviour I'm developing is subtle and difficult to distinguish from the Autonomous Life movements, so I'm trying to make the robot stand still before my behaviour runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ALAutonomousLife API offers the method [setState](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/autonomouslife-api.html?highlight=autonomous#ALAutonomousLifeProxy::setState__ssCR)

In Choregraph you could make a python box with this content:

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)
        self.al = ALProxy("ALAutonomousLife")

    def onLoad(self):
        #put initialization code here
        pass

    def onUnload(self):
        #put clean-up code here
        pass

    def onInput_onStart(self):
        self.al.setState("disabled")
        #self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
        pass

    def onInput_onStop(self):
        self.onUnload() #it is recommended to reuse the clean-up as the box is stopped
        self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
```

And then activate this Box to disable AutonomousLife.

You can also test it in a python console like this:

```
import naoqi
from naoqi import ALProxy
al = ALProxy("ALAutonomousLife", "pepper.local", 9559)
al.setState("diabled")
```

This will have the same effect as pressign the chest button twice.

To only disable subtle autonomous movement have a look at [Autonomous Abilities](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/ref/life/autonomous_abilities_management.html#autonomous-abilities-management)

A method `setEnabled` is offered by

- [ALListeningMovement](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/autonomousabilities/allisteningmovement-api.html#ALListeningMovementProxy::setEnabled__bCR)
- [ALBackgroundMovement](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/autonomousabilities/albackgroundmovement-api.html#ALBackgroundMovementProxy::setEnabled__b)
- [ALSpeakingMovement](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/autonomousabilities/alspeakingmovement-api.html)

Comment: Thanks @TVK. However, whist it does turn off Autonomous Life, it also puts the robot into the rest position.  I need it to stay in the wake state, but without autonomous life running.  Nevertheless, I get the idea of how to go about it now (I've never touched the python code behind the Box tools).  I'll work it out and post a comment so you can update the answer.

Comment: From the documentation, only the `disabled` state can be entered programmatically.  The other three states, `interactive, safeguard, solitary` are internal ALAutonomousLife states.  In your example, `self.onStopped()` in `def onInput_onStart(self):` needs to be uncommented, otherwise the behaviour doesn't continue to the next Box tool.

Comment: Well you asked how to programatically archive the same behavour like pressing the chest button twice. That I answered. 
For what you really want, you should have a look into http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/ref/life/autonomous_abilities_management.html#autonomous-abilities-management

Comment: Your answers have helped me better understand what's going on, and I thank you for that.  When I asked my question, I had no idea that this would be an issue.  In my opinion, autonomous life and whether the robot is standing or resting are two separate concerns, but obviously Aldebaren think otherwise.  I have tried setting the background strategy to `none` using `self.alMove.setBackgroundStrategy("none")`, but NaoQi keeps resetting the background strategy back to `backToNeutral`.  I'll just keep plugging away till I get it.  Then you can update your answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: I think at least an upvote would be reasonable!
ALAutonomousMoves is deprecated and most of its functionalities were moved to new modules: ALBackgroundMovement and ALListeningMovement.